# Magento2 500 error when viewing products in admin - after Migration

Tags: magento2, http-error-500

I've just migrated to a MAgento 2.2.5 website.

It was generally successful except for one issue.

When trying to click into a specific product in the admin area I get a 500 error.

The server reports this as follows...

```
 client denied by server configuration: app/etc/config.php
```

From my understanding this is a permissions issues, right? The etc folder has 755 set. It is strange that is affects products only.

I've cleared cache and index.

Any help would be appreciated.